# URI duplication in HTTP Actions

Tags: azure-logic-apps

In our Logic App, if we run two HTTP POST actions in parallel (with separate URI's), they will sometimes call the same URI. We been able to replicate this several times. Has anyone else seen this? Attached  is an image to make it more clear: In Designer the URIs differ between  the branches, but at run times they are the same, sometimes.

[image: In Designer the URIs differ between the branches, but at run times they are the same]

Comment: Look like a bug.  I you ask this over at MSDN, better change someone close to the Logic Apps team will see it.

Comment: Thanks I agree and opened a case w/MS yesterday